# Why does index.html have such a name in Django?

Tags: html, django, index.html

I’m not a native speaker and I don’t understand why the standard name of the initial page in Django applications is index.html. Can someone explain in simple words why this is so, and not, for example, home.html

I'm trying to find out the answer to my question. I just need a verbal explanation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server_directory_index - this is (much) older than Django

Comment: Has not much to do with Django at all. The path by the way is seldomly `index.html`, since Django does not work with extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not a native speaker and I don’t understand why the standard name of the initial page in Django applications is index.html.

It **isn't**, Django recommends *not* to name pages with an extension. The basic path used is:

```
#    🖟🖟 empty
path('', views.index, name='index')
```

so for the "outside world", we use the empty path, and you can name the view whatever you like.

The tradition to name such file `index.html` originates from the fact that in the very old days, web servers were often seen as "file repositories". So a lot of webservers stored a file named `foo.txt`, and you accessed it with `domain.com/foo.txt`. Now if one visited the `domain.com/` itself, one expects a "list" of the files available, so an index, since a book contains often also a list of the content named the "index" section.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what that file has been called long before Django even existed.